# Error StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]:PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, glassfish-3, mojarra

In my managedBean if I change my scope from `@RequestScoped` to `@ViewScoped`, I am getting the following error stack. How can I resolve this? I could see the results in page when I run my application though.

I am running on glassfish 3 with Mojarra 2.1.3 (FCS b02)

Regards

```
    WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: 
PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
    java.io.NotSerializableException: bean
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1164)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
        at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:570)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:945)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1469)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
        at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1001)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:945)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1469)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1346)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1154)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
        at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1001)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:945)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1469)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.doWriteState(ClientSideStateHelper.java:325)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.writeState(ClientSideStateHelper.java:173)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ResponseStateManagerImpl.writeState(ResponseStateManagerImpl.java:122)
        at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.writeState(StateManagerImpl.java:166)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:225)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:418)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Update 1

```
public class SchedulesBean implements Serializable {

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName().toString());
    CommonMethods commonMethods = new CommonMethods();
    private ScheduleDAO scheduleDAO = DatabaseConnection
            .getInstance(commonMethods.getDSName()).geScheduleDAO();
    List<Schedule> beanValues = new ArrayList<Schedule>();
    private Schedule schedule;

    private Schedule selectedRow  = new Schedule();

    public SchedulesBean() {

        this.getSchedules();                
    }

    public Schedule getSchedule() {
        return schedule;
    }

    public void setSchedule(Schedule schedule) {
        this.schedule = schedule;
    }

    public void getSchedules() {

        try {
            beanValues = scheduleDAO.loadSchedules();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

    }

    public void selectedRow(SelectEvent event) {
        selectedRow = (Schedule) event.getObject();
        logger.info("selectedRow "+selectedRow);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let your bean implement the java.io.Serializable interface. The problem gets solved.

Comment: I already have `public class bean implements Serializable {` or am I missing something?

Comment: How about Schedule and ScheduleDAO classes. May be these require to implement Serializable according to your usage

Comment: I added in Schedule and ScheduleDAO. Now I am getting this error stack `java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1164)` So how could I add in external classes

Comment: clean and rebuild the project afresh

Comment: I did clean and build the project, but same error `java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1164)`

Comment: Just make the logger `static`. It's the same for every class instance anyway.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks. When I change my scope to Viewscoped why I have to implement Serializable for all my classes?

Comment: Because the server is apparently storing sessions on disk instead of in memory. This is a configuration matter.

Comment: @BalusC Ok. is it best to use RequestScoped or ViewScoped? Besides I have noticed that when someone post an answer or comment there is no small red mark below StackExchange which used to appear on top of the screen. since yesterday samll red mark is missing!

Comment: The best scope depends on the data the bean holds. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope Session serialization should in no way be taken into account for the choice.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to add "transient" keyword for all non-serializable properties.

```
transient Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(...

transient private ScheduleDAO scheduleDAO
```

Another way to check if the bean is serializable is to apply QA tool against your code like [Findbugs (TM)](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/), or any home-tools to check this aspect of your code.